# Утилита для создания дампа

Tags: mysql

какую Утилиту можно использовать которая позволяет получить дамп содержимого базы данных или совокупности баз для создания резервной копии или пересылки данных на другой SQL-сервер (не обязательно MySQL-сервер). Дамп будет содержать набор команд SQL для создания и/или заполнения таблиц?.Это моя курсовая подскажите пожалуйста!!!заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь утилитой mysqldump

Answer (score 1):

**Для linux:**

Создание дампа (экспорт):

```bash
mysqldump --user=username --password=password dbname > dump.sql;
```

Загрузка дампа (импорт):

```bash
mysql --user=username --password=password --default-character-set=utf8 dbname < dump.sql;
```

**Для Win:**

Создание дампа (экспорт):

```bash
путь\к\mysqldump.exe -uuser dbname > path\to\dump.sql
```

Загрузка дампа (импорт):

```bash
путь\к\mysql.exe -uroot
mysql> use db_name;
source path\to\db_dump.sql;
```

Немного подробнее [тут](http://valerij.pp.ua/mysql-dump-linux-windows/) и там же можно скачать mysqldump.exe для Windows